# Отсутствует перевод на странице проверки вопроса из очереди

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

Заметил отсутствие перевода на скрине ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

плюс несколько непонятно что вообще здесь в строке хочется чтобы было. Ладно ещё показы, с ними все понятно, а 1 к чему? В traducir есть такие переводы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[вот страница](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Score%20of) на скрине выше из traducir. Добавил перевод такого плана:

> Оценка $__count$

с placeholder не уверен что работать так нужно если честно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут скорее всего нужны переводы «[score of $score](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Score%20of%20%5C%24S)….». Добавил перевод. Ожидаем в новых сборках. Текущая 2022.8.23.42893

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь ;D